# Finding out same colored block in a 2D matrix

Tags: python, c, matrix, puzzle

I am trying to find out a block of same colored region starting from the top left corner in a 2D matrix. For example: I have the following Matrix:

```
1 1 1 2 2 3
1 1 2 3 4 5
1 1 1 1 3 4
1 4 3 2 1 5
2 3 4 5 1 2
```

say, The initial top left corner is 1 and I want to find out the adjacent area containing 1's (I will only consider starting from the top left corner). In the above matrix the digits 1,2,3,4,5 represent different colors. I have tried using the following code segment for finding out the same colored block:

```
colors = ["red", "green", "blue", "purple", "orange"]

# create an array of the colors so we can do work on it
colors_array = [[random.randint(0, len(colors)-1) for x in range(num_wide)] for x in range(num_high)]

// keep track of what colors are touching in a giant array
touching_array = [[[0 for x in range(num_col)] for x in range(num_row)] for x in range(len(colors))]
origin_color = colors_array[0][0]
for x in range(num_row):
for y in range(num_col):
    # first row only cares about what's to the left of it
    if (x == 0):
        # if this is the same color as the origin
        if colors_array[x][y] == origin_color:
            # store a '1' signifying that this color is touching
            touching_array[origin_color][x][y] = 1
        else:
            # once they don't match, stop looking
            break
    # other rows need to match the row above it
    else:
        # if this color is the same color as the origin
        if (colors_array[x][y] == origin_color):
            # AND the one above it is "touching"
            if (colors_array[x][y] == touching_array[origin_color][x-1][y]):
                # store a '1' signifying that this color is touching
                touching_array[origin_color][x][y] = 1
```

But I haven't got the same colored block starting from top left corner as output. Is there anything wrong in the above code segment? How will I make it correct? It would be better If someone provide a C/C++ solution of the above problem.

Comment: You say you want an "area" or a "block". Is that an rectangular region or any arbitrarily connected area? In the latter, @Dan Mašek has given you the solution, otherwise you'd probably want to iterate over the resulting touch_array, get the lowest index that is 1 in each line and column and set any higher indices to 0.

Comment: I meant any arbitrarily connected area @StefanS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot that the tiles can touch along both axes, in all 4 directions.

Consider the following input:

```
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 3 1
1 3 3 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 1 1
```

I wrote a new algorithm in two versions -- one using recursion, the other a loop and queue. It is similar to what [J.Mac](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5609680/j-mac) described in his answer.

The algorithm is simple. We are given a *target color* to search for, the *position* to search at, an input *matrix of colors*, and output *matrix of flags* to identify matched tiles.

To search a tile:

- If the tile has the correct color AND it is not marked

  - Mark the tile
  - Search all neighboring tiles (2-4 depending on whether we're in the middle, at the edge or in the corner).

We can either use recursion to search the neighboring tiles, or we can use a queue to keep track of the tiles that still need to be searched and repeatedly searching tiles from the front of the queue until none remain.

```
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::vector<int32_t> vec_1d;
typedef std::vector<vec_1d> vec_2d;

// Print the 2d vector with a label
void dump(std::string const& label, vec_2d const& v)
{
    std::cout << label << "\n";
    for (std::size_t y(0); y < v.size(); ++y) {
        for (std::size_t x(0); x < v[0].size(); ++x) {
            std::cout << v[y][x] << " ";
        }
        std::cout << "\n";
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}

// Recursive implementation of the search
void find_connected_r(int32_t target_color
    , std::size_t x
    , std::size_t y
    , vec_2d const& colors
    , vec_2d& result)
{
    if ((result[y][x] == 1) || (colors[y][x] != target_color)) {
        return;
    }

    result[y][x] = 1;

    std::size_t width(colors[0].size());
    std::size_t height(colors.size());

    if (x > 0) {
        find_connected_r(target_color, x - 1, y, colors, result);
    }
    if (y > 0) {
        find_connected_r(target_color, x, y - 1, colors, result);
    }
    if (x < (width - 1)) {
        find_connected_r(target_color, x + 1, y, colors, result);
    }
    if (y < (height - 1)) {
        find_connected_r(target_color, x, y + 1, colors, result);
    }
}

// Non-recursive implementation of the search
void find_connected(int32_t target_color
    , std::size_t x
    , std::size_t y
    , vec_2d const& colors
    , vec_2d& result)
{
    std::size_t width(colors[0].size());
    std::size_t height(colors.size());

    typedef std::pair<std::size_t, std::size_t> position;
    std::queue<position> s;

    s.push(position(x, y));

    while (!s.empty()) {
        position pos(s.front());
        s.pop();

        if (result[pos.second][pos.first] == 1) {
            continue;
        }
        if (colors[pos.second][pos.first] != target_color) {
            continue;
        }
        result[pos.second][pos.first] = 1;

        if (pos.first > 0) {
            s.push(position(pos.first - 1, pos.second));
        }
        if (pos.second > 0) {
            s.push(position(pos.first, pos.second - 1));
        }
        if (pos.first < (width - 1)) {
            s.push(position(pos.first + 1, pos.second));
        }
        if (pos.second < (height - 1)) {
            s.push(position(pos.first, pos.second + 1));
        }
    }
}

// Entry point to the search, select the implementation with last param
vec_2d find_connected(std::size_t x, std::size_t y, vec_2d const& colors, bool recursive)
{
    if (colors.empty() || colors[0].empty()) {
        throw std::runtime_error("Invalid input array size");
    }

    int32_t target_color(colors[y][x]);

    vec_2d result(colors.size(), vec_1d(colors[0].size(), 0));

    if (recursive) {
        find_connected_r(target_color, x, y, colors, result);
    } else {
        find_connected(target_color, x, y, colors, result);
    }

    return result;
}



int main()
{
    vec_2d colors{
        { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
        , { 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1 }
        , { 1, 3, 3, 3, 3, 1 }
        , { 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 }
    };

    dump("Input", colors);
    dump("Search from (0,0) Recursive", find_connected(0, 0, colors, true));
    dump("Search from (0,0) Loop", find_connected(0, 0, colors, false));
    dump("Search from (1,1) Recursive", find_connected(1, 1, colors, true));
    dump("Search from (1,1) Loop", find_connected(1, 1, colors, false));
    dump("Search from (1,3) Recursive", find_connected(1, 3, colors, true));
    dump("Search from (1,3) Loop", find_connected(1, 3, colors, false));
}
```

Output:

```
Input
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 3 1
1 3 3 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

Search from (0,0) Recursive
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

Search from (0,0) Loop
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

Search from (1,1) Recursive
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Search from (1,1) Loop
0 0 0 0 0 0
1 1 1 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Search from (1,3) Recursive
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Search from (1,3) Loop
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0
```

---

## Printing coordinates

This is very simple, like `dump(...)`.

We iterate through all the elements, but instead of printing values we print coordinates, and only when the element value is not 0.

```
void dump_coordinates(std::string const& label, vec_2d const& v)
{
    std::cout << label << "\n";
    for (std::size_t y(0); y < v.size(); ++y) {
        for (std::size_t x(0); x < v[0].size(); ++x) {
            if (v[y][x]) {
                std::cout << "(" << x << ", " << y << ") ";
            }
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Call it:

```
dump_coordinates("Coordinates searching from (1,3)", find_connected(1, 3, colors, true));
```

And you get:

```
Input
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 3 1
1 3 3 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

...

Search from (1,3) Loop
0 0 0 0 0 0
0 0 0 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 1 0
0 1 1 1 1 0
0 0 0 0 0 0

Coordinates searching from (1,3)
(3, 1) (4, 1) (4, 2) (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 3) (4, 3)
```

NB: Coordinates are (row, column), and both are 0-indexed. The coordinates are **not** sorted in order of search.

---

## Replacing connected elements with another color

Since we already have a method to obtain a mask of all the connected elements, we just need to use this mask to change all the appropriate values.

This is similar to what we did in `dump_coordinates(...)`.

Again, we iterate over all the elements, but this time instead of printing, we change the color value at given position when the mask value is not 0.

Code:

```
vec_2d& change_masked(int32_t new_color
    , vec_2d& colors
    , vec_2d const& mask)
{
    for (std::size_t y(0); y < mask.size(); ++y) {
        for (std::size_t x(0); x < mask[0].size(); ++x) {
            if (mask[y][x]) {
                colors[y][x] = new_color;
            }
        }
    }

    return colors;
}
```

Call it:

```
dump("Search from (0,0), replace all found with color from (1,1)"
    , change_masked(colors[1][1], colors, find_connected(0, 0, colors, true)));
```

Output:

```
Input
1 1 1 1 1 1
2 2 2 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 3 1
1 3 3 3 3 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

Search from (0,0) Recursive
1 1 1 1 1 1
0 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 0 1
1 0 0 0 0 1
1 1 1 1 1 1

...

Search from (0,0), replace all found with color from (1,1)
2 2 2 2 2 2
2 2 2 3 3 2
2 2 2 2 3 2
2 3 3 3 3 2
2 2 2 2 2 2
```

Comment: can you please provide a c/c++ version of the code segment you provided? @Dan Mašek

Comment: @user4650623 Sure, but your code sample is in Python and there's no mention that you're actually looking for a c++ solution. The unexplained "c" tag is somewhat odd as well. You should be clear in your question about what it is you actually want.

Comment: I have got so many errors while trying to compile the c++ version of your code using CodeBlocks @Dan Mašek

Comment: What errors? It's c++11 compliant code. Compiles fine with MSVS 2013, g++ 5.3.0 on [coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d2a6127d3e4206ee), g++ 4.8, clang 3.7,...

Comment: will the above code work if I want to find the same colored blocks at any position in the matrix? is it possible to make a generic function to perform this operation by modifing the code? @Dan Mašek

Comment: can you provide the generic one? @Dan Mašek

Comment: Is there any way to print the adjacent positions of the found same colored block in (x,y) format? @Dan Mašek

Comment: @user4650623 Sure, extremely simple. See the answer.

Comment: ok. If I want to turn the whole matrix into a single color (all 1 or 2 or 3 or 4 or 5) starting from the top left corner block using the adjacent block nodes color by the above procedure, is it possible to do so? @Dan Mašek

Comment: @user4650623 I'm not sure I understand what you mean by that. Could you please add all your extra requests to your original question, providing appropriate examples of what you wish to achieve?

Comment: I am trying to find a solution of the puzzle game 'Flood It'. The main idea is to turn a whole N*M game board of k different colors into a single color. I have to start from the top left corner of the board and turn the same colored block into one of the colors of neighboring nodes and thus moving ahead and flooding the whole board into a single color at last. You can check [this game](http://unixpapa.com/floodit/).I want to solve it @Dan Mašek

Comment: sir, in your above code does the result generated from Coordinates searching from (1,3)
(3, 1) (4, 1) (4, 2) (1, 3) (2, 3) (3, 3) (4, 3) correct? @Dan Mašek

Comment: Yes, I expanded on that section, hopefully that will clear it up. Regarding solving the game, that seems quite beyond the scope of the original question. The code above should give you a good foundation to work from.

Comment: But how will i choose the color automatically from the neighboring nodes? Is there any way to choose it from the neighbor that has the largest block? @Dan Mašek

Comment: @user4650623 Let's wrap this up, and let's continue in [this followup question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36359856/turning-a-2d-array-of-different-color-into-a-single-color).

Answer (score 1):

I think you might have a problem with your code in the following case:

```
 1 1 2
 1 1 A
 1 1 1
```

Imagine A's color was 1. It should be stored as touching, but as the block above isn't of the same color, A will be considered as not touching.

---

My approach for this kind of algorithm would be something like the following pseudo-code (although yours seems good if the above is fixed)

```
  /** Method to find all touching blocks of the same color */
    void findColoredNeighbors(Block block){
      // Add current block to 'touching'
      touching_array[block.x][block.y] = 1;

      // Check all adyacent blocks to see if any of them matches the color
      for (Position position: getAdyacentBlocks(block)){
          // If a block matches the color, we have to make sure it isn't stored
          // as touching yet to avoid infite recursion
          if((colors_array[position.x][position.y] == block.color) && (touching_array[position.x][position.y] != 1))
              findColoredNeighbors(getBlock(position.x, position.y));       
      }
    }
```

This method assumes that you clear touching_array before calling it, and you have a `getAdyacentBlocks(Block b)` which returns a list of the blocks next to the one passed as parameter.

Hope it helps!